# javascript combine array of object based on a single item object array in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following data

```
var data = [
  {username:'andy', entries:[{time_in:12, ..},{time_in:334,...}]},
  {username:'andy2', entries:[{time_in:'sr12', ..},{time_in:334,...}]}
]
```

What am looking forward to get is a final data with

```
var result = [
  {username:'andy', entry:12},
  {username:'andy', entry:334},
  {username:'andy2', entry:'sr12'},
  {username:'andy2', entry:334},
]
```

There are more properties per array object but for brevity i have included only username

So i have tried

```
data.forEach(item=>{
  item.entries.forEach(entry=>{
    //am stuck here
  })
})
```

Comment: You want to merge the objects into a single one? Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` with `array#forEach`. Iterate through each object and for each object iterate through `entries` array, add the new object in an accumulator.

```js
const data = [
  {username: 'andy', entries: [{time_in: 12}, {time_in: 334}]},
  {username: 'andy2', entries: [{time_in: 'sr12'}, {time_in: 334}]}
]

const result = data.reduce((r, {username, entries}) => {
  entries.forEach(({time_in: entry}) => r.push({username, entry}))
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const final = [];
data.forEach(item =>
  item.entries.forEach(entry =>
    final.push({ username: item.username, entry: entry.time_in })
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would do the trick:

```
var result = data.map((item) => {
    return {
        username: item.username,
        entries: item.entries.length, // Or whatever processing you want
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the immutable version:

```js
const data=[
  {
    username:'andy', entries:[{time_in:12},{time_in:334}]
  }, {
    username:'andy2', entries:[{time_in:'sr12'},{time_in:334}]
  }
];
    

const x = data.reduce((acc, {username, entries}) =>
  acc.concat(
   entries.map(({time_in}) => ({
        username,
        time_in
    }))
  )
, []);
  
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
const result = data.map(({username, entries}) =>
    entries.map(({time_in})=> ({username: username, entry: time_in}))
).reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, ...val], [])
```